# How to not add a couple of key, value in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a list of dict and I want to check if this pair is not in my list. But it doesn't work.

```py
wizards = [Wiz_1, Wiz_2, Wiz_3, Wiz_1]
my_list = []
for wiz in wizards:
    if wiz.first_name not in my_list and wiz.last_name not in my_list:
        my_list.append({"first_name": "Harry", "last_name": "Potter"})
```

Comment: what is `names` , `first_name`, `last_name`? this code is not a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: sorry I have edited my post.

Comment: You need a simple `if name not in my_list:`. And of course you have to fix the definition of `names`. The dictionary `{first_name: "Harry", last_name: "Potter"}` should be defined as `{'first_name': "Harry", 'last_name': "Potter"}`.

Comment: there are more info sorry in fact there are object instances

Comment: your last line is still wrong, you never defined first_name or last_name

Comment: they are just keys

Comment: Keys to what. You need to include relevant code.

Comment: There are no mistakes but the condition isn't working. I have python objects but I need a list of dict that's why that seems odd.

Comment: the reason why people are asking for more clarification is because we want to know if your objects are hashable, clearly `first_name` wouldn't be hashable by default if it was some python object, and some answers will fail if `wiz.first_name` wasn't hashable, you need to be as specific as possible in your question, orelse people simply cannot answer you.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this is to unpack your list into tuples.

```py
wizards = [Wiz_1, Wiz_2, Wiz_3, Wiz_1]
my_list = []
for wiz in wizards:
    if (wiz.first_name, wiz.last_name) not in \
            ((elment["first_name"],elment["last_name"]) for elment in my_list):
        my_list.append({"first_name": wiz.first_name, "last_name": wiz.last_name})
```

this might be a little slow if `wizards` is a list of over 100 elements, so you might want to make a parallel set to avoid iterating over the list on every iteration, as checking membership in a set is O(1) instead of list's O(n).

```py
wizards = [Wiz_1, Wiz_2, Wiz_3, Wiz_1]
my_list = []
my_set = set()
for wiz in wizards:
    if (wiz.first_name, wiz.last_name) not in my_set:
        my_list.append({"first_name": wiz.first_name, "last_name": wiz.last_name})
        my_set.add((wiz.first_name, wiz.last_name))
del my_set
```

note that using [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead of a dictionary as list elements is going to be more convenient, since you seem to be using a dictionary as a namedtuple or a dataclass, which is a frequent beginner mistake that is causing all of these issues.